# cannot allocate vector in R

Tags: r, vector, size, allocation

i'm doing text analisys using R and i created a TermDocumentMatrix using the *tm* library, obtaining a *dtm* object whit the follow characteristic:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 16405, terms: 13002796)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 46650312/213264218068
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 2179
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

that has a size of 1.5 Gb. Now, i want to obtain the frequency of the words, and to do this i have to trasform the *tdm* into a matrix, using the command:

```
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
```

but when i call the function, the program respond with the follow exception:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1589.3 Gb
```

First, why the programm need 1589.3 Gb to store a dtm that has size of 1.5 Gb? Second, how can i solve the problem? Thank to everyone.

Comment: So you want to get frequency of words ? Did you create TDM for that purpose only? What is it you want to do with TDM ?

Comment: mmmmm yes...why?

Comment: Because that's not required. You can directly get the frequency of words without going through this memory intensive process. Check for text2vec or tidytext R package.